# Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, media-queries

In my mediaquery.dart file I got this error in following code:

```
 static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    assert(debugCheckHasMediaQuery(context));
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MediaQuery>()!.data;
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.